# JAVA - JavaFX - Deals with Nodes(e.g.: a JButton) calling another Stage

Tags: stage, scene2d, borderpane, splitpane

I want to have a Main Stage (Main GUI) that will include a Menu Bar at the top, then consist of either an AnchorPane with a vertical SplitPane[split happens at 350pixels] (which contains another horizontal SplitPane on the right side, giving me a total of 3 sections to work with), or a BorderPane which only utilizes the Left,Top, and Center of the BorderPane. In the vertical SplitPane (or Left BorderPane) I want 3 buttons that take up around 320x320 Pixels, leaving a 15 pixel buffer. The Top section[200 pixel heightxMaxValue width] will have an background image, an ImageView, and a Label. Now the Center section of the BorderPane, or Right side of the 1st SplitPane, which contains a horizontal SplitPane, im referencing the bottom side of that SplitPane, will be the biggest area. I want to have 5 buttons in that area, [I can do the sizing and spacing of those buttons, probably use a GridPane inside the bottom section of the horizontal Splitpane] that will become visible when the first button on the Left side is clicked. And then I want to have another 5 different buttons show up when the second button is clicked, removing the first 5 buttons. I don't know if I need to have the buttons on the left side call the GridPane the 5 buttons are in to be visible, or how to set it up. And then I want the buttons inside the GridPane to call another Stage (5 seperate stages actually, but one at a time visible) that covers the entire first stage while it is open. Also, i need this to size to be default size of 1440x900 (minimum size) that opens Maximized. (I can handle that function, i just need the children nodes to resize with it, but only one size. I need the Left Side of the first split pane to resize only height, and the Top section to resize only width. I know, this is alot, but i tried to give as much information as I could. Thank you everyone for your help with this.

Here is the code is have so far:

`javaFX`

```
package scindbmain;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainGUI extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent rootPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("maingui.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Star Citizen InfoNet & Database");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(1440);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(900);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);

     }
}
```

```
And here is my FXML file to go with it:
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1440.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <MenuBar maxHeight="25.0" minHeight="25.0" prefHeight="25.0" style="-fx-background-color: beige;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.18567454798331015" layoutY="29.0" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1440.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0">
        <items>
            <VBox maxWidth="350.0" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="350.0" prefHeight="875.0" prefWidth="350.0" spacing="30.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;">
               <children>
                  <Button maxHeight="300.0" maxWidth="300.0" minHeight="300.0" minWidth="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: silver;" text="Star Systems &amp; Locations" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Impact" size="45.0" />
                     </font>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="25.0" layoutY="25.0" maxHeight="300.0" maxWidth="300.0" minHeight="300.0" minWidth="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: silver;" text="Starships, Weapons &amp; Components" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Impact" size="45.0" />
                     </font>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button layoutX="25.0" layoutY="375.0" maxHeight="300.0" maxWidth="300.0" minHeight="300.0" minWidth="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: silver;" text="Trading, Mining &amp; Refining" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Impact" size="45.0" />
                     </font>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="15.0" left="25.0" right="15.0" top="15.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.22451317296678122" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="160.0">
              <items>
                  <HBox maxHeight="200.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="1090.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="1090.0" spacing="25.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="15.0" top="10.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="180.0" fitWidth="180.0" pickOnBounds="true" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../SCImages/TaktikalLogo1.jpg" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <Label minWidth="1000.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-border-color: white;" text="STAR CITIZEN INFONET &amp; DATABASE" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="true">
                           <HBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                           </HBox.margin>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Mongolian Baiti" size="68.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="668.0" minWidth="1090.0" prefHeight="338.0" prefWidth="1090.0">
                     <children>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="668.0" prefWidth="1090.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                           <children>
                              <GridPane>
                                <columnConstraints>
                                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                                </columnConstraints>
                                <rowConstraints>
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                                </rowConstraints>
                              </GridPane>
                           </children>
                        </StackPane>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

```
Now, as you can see I have coded some of the GUI. And I have 3 buttons on the left side. I want to have each of those buttons call a Pane(AnchorPane,StackPane, i dont know which one) to fill the bottom right of my Stage (bottom half of the horizontal StackPane) with 5 buttons on each pane. Each button will call a different Pane with 5 different buttons that will each call a different stage. But for now, I have problems with the GUI. I have it set to Maximum because if i set it to 1440x900, and set it to not resize, it will still let me resize it down a little bit, and it moves the GUI out of place. I don't think this code is the correct code to do this with, which is why I was asking for someone's example earlier, instead of putting this code up. Thank you for any help.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not about doing your work. You should try to code this for yourself (otherwise how should you learn if you just copy-paste the solution). Then you can show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain where the problem is and ask for some help.

Comment: I was in college 18 years ago, and i just recently started programming again. I have some of this code already, should i post it here? I did some in with java scene builder and some with just IntelliJ. This is my first post here so I'm new. I don't mind showing what I have to get help with, and by no means do I want people doing my work. Even if people can give me pieces of examples with part of my problem would be great. Thank you for your comment.